# How do I return a list of ParseObjects to Unity from a Parse cloud function?

Tags: javascript, c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, cloud

Using the code below, I am able to return a single LeaderboardScore back to Unity, however what I want to do is to return `scoreResults` and end up with a **list** of LeaderboardScores in Unity.

I am not sure what type I need to specify on the Unity side to make this happen. I would assume that it would just be `IDictionary<string,object>[]` since [Parse.Query.find returns an array of ParseObjects](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html), however when I do that `t.IsFaulted` is true, but no error messages or codes are printed (I think it may be having some trouble casting to ParseException).

If someone can shed any light on what needs to be done here I would really appreciate it :)

**Cloud Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFriendsScores", function(request, response)
{
    // code to get friends

    var scoresQuery = new Parse.Query("LeaderboardScore");
    scoresQuery.containedIn("user", parseFriends);

    scoresQuery.find(
    {
        success: function(scoreResults)
        {
            response.success(scoreResults[0]);
        },
        error: function(scoreError)
        {
            console.log('No matching scores found...');
        }
    });
}
```

**Unity Code**

```
ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>("getFriendsScores", parameters).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        foreach (var e in t.Exception.InnerExceptions)
        {
            ParseException parseException = e as ParseException;
            Debug.Log("Error message " + parseException.Message);
            Debug.Log("Error code: " + parseException.Code);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Success!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working by using the following type in Unity:

`<IList<IDictionary<string, object>>>`

A single ParseObject is returned as an object that implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, and when you ask for a list, it gives you a List of those (I just used IList because it is more generic).

For anyone else struggling with figuring out the return type of these kind of functions, just do something like this and you'll work it out:

```
ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<object>("functionName", parameters).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    Debug.Log(t.Result.GetType().ToString());
}
```